# GitHub README does not show external image on AWS S3

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I have the following markup inside my README file.

```
![](https://cs-challenge.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/4281a2523dc3b47813316b0400549a6295a55f05.png)
```

HTML also does now work,

```
<img src="https://cs-challenge.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/4281a2523dc3b47813316b0400549a6295a55f05.png" />
```

Snowy mountains illustration Designed by Freepik

(It works on StackOverflow)

[image]

GitHub does not render the markup properly, which converts the markdown markup above into something below,

```
<p><a href="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/15e4c167d484297001c34549a2cc69f0ddc80704/68747470733a2f2f63732d6368616c6c656e67652e73332d61702d736f757468656173742d312e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f343238316132353233646333623437383133333136623034303035343961363239356135356630352e706e67" target="_blank"><img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/15e4c167d484297001c34549a2cc69f0ddc80704/68747470733a2f2f63732d6368616c6c656e67652e73332d61702d736f757468656173742d312e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f343238316132353233646333623437383133333136623034303035343961363239356135356630352e706e67" alt="" data-canonical-src="https://cs-challenge.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/4281a2523dc3b47813316b0400549a6295a55f05.png" style="max-width:100%;"></a></p>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that I did not set the **Metadata** for the image stored on AWS S3. All I need to do is to assign the correct metadata type to the file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use  tag directly in markdown, something like

```
<img src='https://cs-challenge.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/4281a2523dc3b47813316b0400549a6295a55f05.png' width: 300 />
```

Comment: Maybe a "width" attribute is required? See this example https://github.com/xlk3099/smartparking_client

Comment: <img src="/screenshots/4.png" width="300"> The repo you provided use relative link to the repo

Comment: Your HTML syntax is not even correct. <img src="/screenshots/4.png" width="300">

Comment: well that was the outcome after Github style check. Github recognise it correctly if you try it.

Comment: see https://github.com/xlk3099/smartparking_client/blob/liusy182/README.md

Comment: its working now because I have added the content type to the image.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the style.