# Github README.md file is only partially displaying my image

Tags: github, version-control, markdown

I'm trying to display an image in the README.md file of my github repository. 
The image is hosted on an AWS S3 bucket, and is configured with the following metadata information, as per [GitHub README does now show external image on AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904978/github-readme-does-now-show-external-image-on-aws-s3).

[Image Meta Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhZkY.png)

In my README.md file, the link for the above is written as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO6HQ.png)

But my github repo displays the image with most of it missing:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcoQY.png)

Github Repo:

https://github.com/bransfieldjack/bransfieldjack.github.io

Comment: Link us to the Github repo. To me, that just looks like a partially downloaded file.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same, link added above &:
https://github.com/bransfieldjack/bransfieldjack.github.io

Comment: Looks like Github proxies images (https://camo.githubusercontent.com/1deff61181b01d137999842cc32c9e1b878bd5a1/68747470733a2f2f73332d61702d736f757468656173742d322e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f73747265616d2d6f6e652d70726f6a6563742f756e69745f74657374696e675f6e61766261725f69737375652e706e67; likely for privacy reasons), and it didn't load right - possibly because it's a huge 1MB+ image. I'd try changing the image URL to bypass the bad cached image, and report to Github support if it happens again.

Comment: The issue was the size of the image, I have replaced it with a smaller one and now it displays without any problems. Thanks

https://github.com/bransfieldjack/bransfieldjack.github.io/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the size of the image, I have replaced it with a smaller one and now it displays without any problems

Comment: Checked again today and the same thing has happened with the smaller image.